# kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.SearchView

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview

i wanted to learn how to implement the SearchView in a app, so i created a new Android-Project and followed the [google documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog#kotlin) for that.

so i already done this steps: 
1 - i added the intent-filter and meta-data in the AndroidManifest and created the searchable configuration in the xml directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:hint="search hint"
            android:label="@string/app_name"> 
</searchable>
```

2 - created the menu file with the icon needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/searchIcon"
          android:title="search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
          app:showAsAction="always"
    />
</menu>
```

in the MainActivity i tried to inflate the menu and try to show the searchView on Click.

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)

        val searchmanager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
        (menu?.findItem(R.id.searchIcon)?.actionView as SearchView).apply {
            setSearchableInfo(searchmanager.getSearchableInfo(componentName))
        }

        return true
    }
```

but when i run the app, i get this error.

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.SearchView
        at com.example.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.kt:30)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3373)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:378)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2549)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1589)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$2.run(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:230)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

the dependencies in my Gradle (Module:app)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

can someone explain please why is this happen and how to fix.

thank you in advance

Comment: You need to specify `android:actionView` in your item tag.

Comment: @TheWanderer `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"` or rather `android:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"` to be precise. I'm going to vote to close this as a typographical error.

Comment: @TheWanderer it's already done in this line of code (menu?.findItem(R.id.searchIcon)?.actionView as SearchView

Comment: @korchix The `item` tag in your menu XML is incomplete. You can't access the `actionView` in code if you don't specify it's supposed to be there in XML. Check the tutorial again, it's there.

Comment: @korchix this reference should be useful, as it shows how to use the `app:actionViewClass` XML attribute: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views#action-view

Comment: @EugenPechanec ok, thank you, i will check this

Comment: @Wang thank you for the link, i will check it.

Comment: @EugenPechanec you had right, i added this two tags the the item of the view in the menu.xml `app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"` after that it works. thank you . if you answer my question i will choose yours as the right answer, and give you a thumps up